# An unknown N1QL error occured. This is usually related to an out-of-memory condition when fatch data

Tags: sql++

An unknown N1QL error occured. This is usually related to an  out-of-memory condition. Check the errors responseBody property or inspect the cluster logs for further details

please help me how to solve the issue.

Comment: This is not N1QL issue. Make sure 8093 port is open as described https://forums.couchbase.com/t/error-an-unknown-n1ql-error-occured-this-is-usually-related-to-an-out-of-memory-condition/7524/19

Comment: Thanks ypur for reply

Comment: If that worked. Could you post solution so that others can benefit.

Comment: no , its not working still now